# Parse winff xml file to create a menu with kdialog and bash

Tags: xml, bash, parsing

i just did a little work for ffmpeg and it works fine ...

it reads  a file where are stored profiles in this way:

name_myprofile mp4 ffmpeg options

now i would like use winff functions  that is an xml file

http://winff.googlecode.com/files/presets-libavcodec53-v3.xml.gz

but i really i have no idea how to convert

```
<H105FS>
<label>RB iRiver H10 5/6GB Fullscreen</label>
<params>-acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -vcodec mpeg2video -vf scale=128:96 -b 224k -strict -1</params>
<extension>mpg</extension>
<category>Rockbox</category>
```

in this

RB_iRiver_H10_5/6GB_Fullscreen mpg  -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -vcodec mpeg2video -vf scale=128:96 -b 224k -strict -1

thanks!!

maybe with awk ... mah .. i am working on it but :S

edit i was be able to print some stuff using

```
awk '/params/{gsub(/<params>/,"");gsub(/<\/params>/,"");gsub(/    /,"") ;print }' presets-libavcodec51-v5.xml >>params


awk '/label/{gsub(/<label>/,"");gsub(/<\/label>/,"");gsub(/    /,"");gsub(/ /,"_") ;print }' presets-libavcodec51-v5.xml >>presetlabel



awk '/extension/{gsub(/<extension>/,"");gsub(/<\/extension>/,"");gsub(/    /,"") ;print }' presets-libavcodec51-v5.xml
```

:D but i need to print it better :S

Comment: i guess i did `awk 'BEGIN{j=1;i=1;h=1} /params/{gsub(/<params>/,"");gsub(/<\/params>/,"");gsub(/    /,"") ;ar[j] = $0 ; j++} 
/label/{gsub(/<label>/,"");gsub(/<\/label>/,"");gsub(/    /,"");gsub(/ /,"_") ; br[i] = $1; i++ } 
/extension/{gsub(/<extension>/,"");gsub(/<\/extension>/,"");gsub(/    /,"") ;cr[h] = $1  ; h++ }END { for (j in ar) {print br[j]" "cr[j]" "ar[j]  } }' presets-libavcodec51-v5.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{j=1;i=1;h=1} /params/{gsub(/<params>/,"");gsub(/<\/params>/,"");gsub(/    /,"") ;ar[j] = $0 ; j++} 
/label/{gsub(/<label>/,"");gsub(/<\/label>/,"");gsub(/    /,"");gsub(/ /,"_") ; br[i] = $1; i++ } 
/extension/{gsub(/<extension>/,"");gsub(/<\/extension>/,"");gsub(/    /,"") ;cr[h] = $1  ; h++ }END { for (j in ar) {print br[j]" "cr[j]" "ar[j]  } }' presets-libavcodec51-v5.xml
```

here it is :D